# Why does the main thread get stuck in pthread_create() case?

Tags: c, multithreading

When looking at this code someone noted that the main thread might get stuck and not finish the main function :
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDZXs.png)

> ```C
> int count = numThreads;
>
> void* bar(void* arg) {
>     /* do some stuff */
>     --count;
> }
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
>     /* ... initialize everything ... */
>     for (i = 0 ; i < numThreads; ++i)
>         pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,bar,NULL);
>
>     while (count > 0)
>         sleep(1);
> }
> ```
>
> Is the above code correct?
>
> (א) Yes. (ב) Yes if no signals are sent to the process during the run. (ג) No, the main thread may not finish. (ד) No, the main thread may finish before all the [other] threads finish.

How come it gets stuck if the bar() has no infinite loops?

Comment: Please do not post code as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. As a new user please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Re, "..someone noted..." This looks like a homework question or a test prep question. Someone told you that the correct answer is (ג). If you don't understand why, then you may receive more benefit from talking about it with your instructor than you'll receive by taking advice from random people here.

Comment: If `create_thread` fails, `counter` never gets to `zero`.

Comment: P.S., if you want to do your own research, Then you might want to read up on the [C Memory Model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model), and ask yourself whether the assignment of `count` by any of the `bar` threads _happens before_ the `count>0` test in the main thread. (Note: "happens before" has a very specific, formal meaning when it appears in a programming language specification, and it's not quite the same as what we mean when we say it in common speech.)

Answer (score 0):

Both ג and ד are correct answers.  This code has a [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model), because the non-atomic variable `count` is written concurrently with other accesses, without mutexes or any other synchronization.  So according to the C standard, its behavior is undefined.  It may finish early, or not finish at all, or crash, or misbehave in any other imaginable fashion.

To see a particular way in which it could loop forever, note that since `count` is not an [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) variable, the decrement `--count` is not an atomic operation.  So it could be implemented by loading the value of `count` from memory, subtracting 1, and storing the new value, and these accesses could be interleaved.  For instance, we could have the following sequence of events:

1. Thread 1 loads from `count`, getting the value 2
2. Thread 1 decrements 2 and decides it should store the new value 1
3. Thread 2 loads from `count`, getting the value 2
4. Thread 2 decrements 2 and decides it should store the new value 1
5. Thread 1 stores the value 1 to `count`
6. Thread 2 stores the value 1 to `count`

and then both threads finish.  No further writes to `count` will occur, so it will never attain the value 0, and the loop in `main` will never exit.